# How do I configure node-http-proxy for outgoing requests?

Tags: node-http-proxy

All the examples for `node-http-proxy` show a `{target: <URL>}` option, but I don't want to proxy to a single target.  How do I set it up for outbound requests (to any URL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `node-http-proxy` seems to be a proxy for inbound connections to a server farm, and not for outbound connections to random websites, I found another tool instead:

http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/node-js-http-and-https-proxy/

This allows me to customize the requests and responses as needed.